# Mount XFS partition with < 4k block size

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, partition, xfs

I have an XFS partition with a 64k blocksize.  But I can only mount it in Ubuntu 10.10 when the blocksize is the default of 4k.  How can I mount a partition with the larger blocksize?

This works:

```
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1 -b size=4k -d agcount=32 -l size=128m -f
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media
```

This doesn't work:

```
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1 -b size=64k -d agcount=32 -l size=128m -f
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media
mount: Function not implemented
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because Linux will allow you to *create* an XFS partition with large block-sizes, but can only *mount* an XFS partition that has a block size at or smaller than the memory page size. The memory block size set in all pre-compiled kernels of common distros is 4KB. Check it with `getconf PAGE_SIZE`. You can set it higher, but it requires compiling your own kernel.