# Getting files out of XFS with 64kb block size

Tags: lvm, raid1, data-recovery, xfs, fakeraid

I've been on a mission to recover files from one of my 2 perfectly working, non-corrupted, non-encrypted NAS drives that used to be in RAID 1. The NAS was Patriot Javelin S4, which (as I found from my research) uses Promise Fasttrack fake raid controller.

Information is very scarce on this, so for googlers in the same situation here are some facts about this NAS:

- RAID controller: Promise FastTrack (FakeRaid)
- Volume system: LVM2
- Filesystem: XFS with 64kb block size (65536 bytes)
- Arch: 800MHz AMCC PowerPC processor, 256MB RAM (thanks to Matthew's research)

I only had Windows 10 and MacOS computer when doing this, and I found no software capable of mounting XFS in LVM2 volume (with 1 exception, more on this below). I had to take out my old netbook Acer Aspire One, and install puppy linux on it (specifically lxpup flavor).

On puppy linux I managed to mount this file system using a tool called `dmraid`. This tool has a way of mounting a pdc volume, which is its id for Promise FastTrack. Once I managed to jump through some hoops mounting it, I gained access to the actual XFS filesystem, and to my dismay, it turned out to be 64kb block size.

This is where I started googling things like "read xfs 64kb block size" and getting nowhere. Only a few answers that say: "linux can't read block sizes bigger than 4kb, unless you patch the kernel". I have no idea how to patch the kernel, and I'm baffled that there isn't any kind of emulation to allow this.

I mentioned 1 exception among apps that can't read this partition on Win/Mac. That exception was ufsexplorer. It's a $100 app, it was able to seamlessly show me the files. I copied a few files proving that it works, but the trial version only allows copying tiny files.

I refuse to believe that there isn't a free open source tool out there of any level of complexity that can't help me read 64kb xfs.

**My question is:** does anybody know of any such tool? Any specific instructions on how to get the data using one or more tools, or kernel patching, or something else (free) are greatly appreciated.

One more point: I would highly prefer to not have to create local images of these drives (unless that's the only way). After all, it's 2TB of data, I may not have this much space.

P.S. If there's a known linux I can install on my Acer that can read 64kb xfs, that's a viable solution too.

**Update 1**: I just learned about https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk. Might be worth a shot. Will report back once I had time to try it.

**Update 2**: TestDisk seems to be recognizing the presence of XFS partition, but I'm not sure how to proceed form there. I don't see a way to extract a file, so I just abandoned it for now, and trying the qemu approach in Matthew's answer.

Comment: I see two solutions, build your own custom kernel or make an image with your xfs partition and try to open it under windows by http://www.fs-driver.org/

Comment: @AlexanderT Hi, thanks for responding. Any links about custom kernel? Also, is there perhaps a way to clone the drive into my mac's drive while converting the filesystem on-the-fly? And to be clear: I have the NAS drive hooked up via SATA -> USB converter, so I can plug it directly into windows or mac without making an image.

Comment: Try and see if xfsdump help.

Comment: > it turned out to be 64kb block size. Elaborate on how you came to this conclusion, please

Comment: @poige I ran `file -sL /dev/vg001/lv001` and got `/dev/vg001/lv001: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 65536, inosz 256, v2 dirs)`.

Comment: I see. Well, the thing I'd go for being in your shoes is writing to corresponding mail list: http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_email_list_and_archives

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/246640/mount-xfs-partition-with-4k-block-size

Comment: http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2005-02/msg00461.html — I have a suspicion the CPU of NAS AMCC 431 (800Mhz) Processor could be the one that supports 64k page size

Comment: The linked question has no useful answer.

Comment: @MaxChernyakakahakunin: The answer in the linked question **is** helpful - it's time to learn how to compile a kernel (patching shouldn't be necessary, just select the proper option in the configure process).

Comment: @Sven The linked answer is helpful but not useful. I'd very much like to learn by following step-by-step instructions on how to do this, and I offered a fairly generous bounty for it.

Comment: @MaxChernyakakahakunin: Do you really believe someone spends a few hours writing a tutorial to compile a kernel for 200 fake internet points when he just could say: Use google to learn, this is documented widely.

Comment: @Sven I am not new to the concept of StackExchange. https://stackoverflow.com/users/155351/max-chernyak-aka-hakunin — I understand this is a hard question. I ask questions here very rarely, only when I exhausted all other reasonable (to me) options.

Comment: @Sven To be clear, there is not a single clear answer anywhere on the web on how to extract data out of 64kb XFS filesystem for somebody who simply needs to do that. The community at large would benefit from being brought to one of these answers, and might learn a thing or two about kernel compilation in the process. Clear and direct answers are a gateway to more learning for those wanting to dive deeper.

Comment: Can you run `xfs_info /path/to/block/device` ?

Comment: @MatthewIfe when I run it, I get `xfs info: /dev/vg001/lv001 is not a mounted XFS filesystem` and when I run `mount -t xfs /dev/vg001/lv001 /mnt/` I get `mount: Function not implemented`.

Comment: Do you know what kernel that NAS product ran? It sounds like the XFS build in that kernel doesn't add the page_size == block_size restriction.

Comment: I agree  with @polge : go ask the XFS mailing list. There is no easy workaround unless you have a PPC machine (for instance an old Mac) lying around.

Comment: @wazoox makes sense. I'll try to exhaust the leads I have (TestDisk and qemu), and if they don't work, I will go ahead with the mailing list.

Answer (score 8):

I've done a bit of research into your problem. Not easy but looks feasible.

The area of code breaking you is this (well, in  newer kernels):
`fs/xfs/libxfs/xfs_sb.c`

```
271         /*
272          * Until this is fixed only page-sized or smaller data blocks work.
273          */
274         if (unlikely(sbp->sb_blocksize > PAGE_SIZE)) {
275                 xfs_warn(mp,
276                 "File system with blocksize %d bytes. "
277                 "Only pagesize (%ld) or less will currently work.",
278                                 sbp->sb_blocksize, PAGE_SIZE);
279                 return -ENOSYS;
280         }
```

It basically requires that the XFS block size be at least equal to the systems page size.

This means two things.

1. This is a workaround of a bug previously not known about.
2. The systems page size originally was 64k.

I went and checked a really old kernel (EL4) and that restriction above was still there. This means its fundamentally not feasible to do what you want to do on your architecture (x86).

Given you provided the name of the NAS I did some googling and discovered this:
http://www.techwarelabs.com/patriot-javelin-s4-network-attached-storage/2/

Which implies it uses a PPC CPU.

> The hardware of the Javelin is more than capable of handling
>   additional roles. It is essentially an embedded Linux system with a
>   800 MHz AMCC PowerPC processor and 256 MB of RAM.

Indeed, on PowerPC kernels can be built to use either 64k pages or 4k pages. This would explain why the block is 64k and also why you cant run the filesystem on your machine, where it worked on its own NAS before.

If you want to try to open the filesystem -- I think your best option is to run a virtual machine instance in a hypervisor using PPC64LE (I think thats the actual architecture of that CPU), Fedora build their PPC64LE with 64k pages.

https://alt.fedoraproject.org/alt/

You can use qemu to do this. This guy seems to give some (not tested) instructions on how you'd go about doing this.

https://rwmj.wordpress.com/tag/ppc64le/

From there, directly expose the disk(s) in the VM and do your normal dmraid/lvm/mount to get access to the drive.

Comment: I will report back as soon as I had time to look into qemu approach. Looks very hopeful, appreciate the time you put into this Matthew.

Comment: Currently I'm astuck trying to run `virt-builder fedora-25 --arch ppc64le -o fedora-25-ppc64le.img`. I am on puppy linux and getting "supermin: could not detect package manager used by this system or distro."

Comment: Use a fedora distro to do it.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to finish this attempt yet, but I'm giving you the bounty. I hope I can still follow up as I'm working towards it.

Comment: @hakunin I was able to both format and mount a 64kb xfs filesystem in a ppc64le architecture as I suggested you do earlier this week so I know this will work.

Comment: It's been a while, but I was only now able to revisit this project. I tried putting Fedora on my netbook, and following virt-builder+qemu instructions for ppc64. Got errors that suggested not enough resources. So I switched to VirtualBox on my Mac to run Fedora with qemu with another Fedora (ppc64le). Got further, but it was painful to work in VM-ception, couldn't fix the device/network issues. Looked into installing ppc64le on VirtualBox directly, but couldn't find any info on that. Ended up buying this and it (tauntingly) just works http://www.sysdevlabs.com/order.php?prod=rxs6&os=mac&ltp=p